# Logging specific successful SSH login and disconections

Tags: unix, ssh, pam

Good Day,

I have trying to log successful ssh login and disconnection times for specific users. i.e. I would like to trigger a bash script when the ssh connection is established and when it is closed.

I have been trying to comprehend the PAM.d modules without much success except that pam_exec may be what I am looking for.

Here is the journalctl log when the user I am after disconnects and then reconnects:

```
May 31 00:47:31 myhostname.com sshd[11517]: Connection closed by 41.113.99.123
May 31 00:47:31 myhostname.com sshd[11517]: Transferred: sent 10160, received 12196 bytes
May 31 00:47:31 myhostname.com sshd[11517]: Closing connection to 41.113.99.123 port 24976
May 31 00:47:31 myhostname.com sshd[12377]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user myuser
May 31 00:47:31 myhostname.com systemd-logind[4406]: Removed session 24778.
May 31 00:47:52 myhostname.com sshd[11964]: Connection from 41.113.99.123 port 24989 on 178.79.130.104 port 22
May 31 00:47:55 myhostname.com sshd[11964]: Postponed publickey for myuser from 41.113.99.123 port 24989 ssh2 [preauth]
May 31 00:47:56 myhostname.com sshd[11964]: Accepted publickey for myuser from 41.113.99.123 port 24989 ssh2: RSA SHA256:R0y/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/HuC6vZp/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
May 31 00:47:56 myhostname.com sshd[11964]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user myuser by (uid=0)
May 31 00:47:56 myhostname.com systemd-logind[4406]: New session 24786 of user myuser.
May 31 00:47:56 myhostname.com systemd[1]: Started Session 24786 of user myuser.
May 31 00:47:57 myhostname.com sshd[11964]: User child is on pid 12009
```

Is there an efficient (possibly PAM) way to execute a script when the "session" is closed and opened for "myuser? 
And if possible would it be possible to expose the associated PID as shown in the last line?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, after a lot of searching and experimentation. I came to realization that neither PAM nor all the fancy features of ssh and its daemon could be used to achieve my objective. I found out that establishing an ssh reverse tunnel using the -N option is not the same as a normal ssh login. I'll attempt to explain why.

With that out the way this is what I had done.

[SSH Access Control](http://cromwell-intl.com/linux/ssh-2-access-control.html) is quite nicely summarized in this article. Which illustrates where PAM fits into the SSH process. PAM allows for various "modules" to supplement and enhance the authentication/login process. One such module which I eluded to in my question was pam_exec(). Which I included at the end of the `/etc/pam.d/sshd` file as follows:

```
    session    optional    pam_exec.so debug log=/tmp/pam_exec.log seteuid /usr/local/bin/login_auth
```

The idea was, when a user establishes an ssh connection this would fire of a script that could log/take some action. The script worked however the "shell" in which the command is executed is limited in that is only has a minimal set of session information. i.e. normal SSH environment variables like SSH_CONNECTION were not available and any environment variables sent from the the remote client (`-o SendEnv=LC_MYVAR`) were also not available (`LC_MYVAR`). Turns out this is only true for reverse tunnel type ssh connections which do not typically establish a shell thanks to the -N option.

Anyhow, one could very nicely use the above method to capture the username and ip of any connection and even further information like SSH_CONNECTION for interactive logins.

I need to clarify at this point what I was trying to achieve. I have multiple devices in the "field" that are programmed to establish a reverse ssh tunnel when they can. The idea was to monitor server side when each device connects and disconnects thereby having visibility on connection issues. The problem is that I set them all up with the same user and sshkey. So to differentiate them is only possible on remote port that I set for them to be available through. 2222, 2223,2224,2225,2226, etc. I need to obtain and log this information on connection and disconnection.

Finally I have had to concede and use a log `tail` approach like:

```
tail -F /var/log/auth.log | grep "Connection closed by" | /usr/bin/myscript
```